# c3p0 - Connection Pool Queries for different servers

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, connection-pooling, c3p0

I have created a mavenized web application in java. If I run the web application using maven jetty plug-in, I am able to initialize the data sources from connection pool and also able to get the connection from data sources. But when I deployed the application on tomcat server, it able to initialize the data sources but while trying to get connection its throwing exception :

```
java.sql.SQLException: Connections could not be acquired from the underlying database!
at com.mchange.v2.sql.SqlUtils.toSQLException(SqlUtils.java:106)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:529)
```

Even I have made changes in server.xml for resources and resouces-ref in web.xml but still I am not able to get the connecion.

```
**Server.xml**
<Resource name="jdbc/sample" auth="Container"
 driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
 url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@someServer:1551:xyz"
 username="userName"
 password="pwd"
 validationQuery="SELECT 1 FROM dual"
 testOnBorrow="true"
 testWhileIdle="true"
 factory="org.apache.naming.factory.BeanFactory" 
 type="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" 
 maxPoolSize="20" 
 minPoolSize="5" 
 acquireIncrement="1" 
/>

**web.xml**
<resource-ref>
  <res-ref-name>jdbc/sample</res-ref-name>
  <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
  <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

What I am missing in this scenario while trying to run application on tomcat server?

Answer (score 0):

the properties you are setting on your datasource are not properties of c3p0 ComboPooledDataSource. for example, you set a property called `username`. the ComboPooledDataSource property is `user`. `validationQuery` should be `preferredTestQuery`, `testOnBorrow` should be `testConnectionOnCheckout`, `testWhileIdle` maps to using a nonzero `idleConnectionTestPeriod` etc.

please see [c3p0's docs](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/) for full information about [configuration properties](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#configuration_properties).